# Is it possible to use free Hostring domain as Dynamic Links on Firebase?

Tags: dns, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

When the project was created, two free domains are generated.

`yourproject.web.app` and `yourproject.firebaseapp.com`.

I don't own a custom domain, so I have to implement Dynamic Links for free.
To use Dynamic Links, I must edit the DNS of my domain to authenticate, but I can't find how to edit.

To edit TXT record, open the manage page of the domain in general.
But I can't find the page to do like this.

This means it has no way to change TXT record of free Hosting domain?

Comment: I'm not sure any custom DNS settings should be needed in this scenario, as Firebase Hosting already has verified the ownership of the *.web.app and *.firebasepp.com domains. Can you skip the DNS editing step? If not, can you link me to the exact documentation you're following?

Comment: You can enter `yourproject.page.link` as the domain, `page.link` is [provided by Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links#custom-link-domains) for this purpose.

Comment: make sure project id is without dashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, @abraham!

As he/she said it was able to creat with `project.page.link`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links#custom-link-domains

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).